# Why doesn't the GitHub API return all branches for a repository?

Tags: json, bash, git, parsing, github

As title says. I am facing why [this](https://github.com/bminor/glibc) mirror on GitHub don't show output in terminal using this command:

```
wget --no-check-cert -q -O - "http://api.github.com/repos/bminor/glibc/branches" | grep release
```

but on GitHub there is for example:

[image: picture]

Comment: try `https://...` instead of http

Comment: sorry but there on both is no output

Comment: that api it seems does not produce any output with `release` keyword

Comment: yes, on terminal but I want to list like this on picture I posted. by the way on github web page there are visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response is [paginated](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination). If you look at response headers:

```
Link: <https://api.github.com/repositories/13868694/branches?page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/repositories/13868694/branches?page=10>; rel="last"
```

you'll see that you're looking at page 1 of 10. You can increase the number of records per page using a query string parameter up to 100:

```
curl -Lv 'http://api.github.com/repos/bminor/glibc/branches?per_page=100'
```

but you still have to get the other pages in your case; the desired page is selected using the `page` query string parameter, e.g.:

```
$ curl -sL 'http://api.github.com/repos/bminor/glibc/branches?page=2&per_page=100' \
      | jq -r '.[] | select(.name | contains("release")).name'
hjl/release/2.20/master
hjl/x32/release/2.12
hjl/x32/release/2.15
```

Alternatively, using the GitHub CLI:

```bash
gh api --method GET repos/bminor/glibc/branches \
    --raw-fielg page=2 --raw-field per_page=100 \
    --jq '.[] | select(.name | contains("release")).name'
```